# Binding an existing JavaScript function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Using jQuery I want to bind an existing function to a button. I've been through the documentation and have found the `bind` method but the examples on the jQuery site bind newly created functions where as I want to bind a function that's already defined, e.g:

```
function fHardCodedFunction(){
   //Do stuff
}

function fBindFunctionToElement(){
   $("#MyButton").bind("click", fHardCodedFunction());
}
```

Is this possible? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Here is the related section from the jQuery API documentation:  
[**Multiple Selector**](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The plain `fHardCodedFunction` already refers to the function and the suffix `()` will just call it. So just pass the function instead of calling it and thereby just passing the return value:

```
function fBindFunctionToElement(){
   $("#MyButton").bind("click", fHardCodedFunction);
}
```

Comment: @Jack Mills: Then you will need to use an (anonymous) wrapping function like `function() { return fHardCodedFunction("foo","bar"); }` that you pass as callback function to `bind`.

Comment: This is almost what I'm trying to do (I'm using .click() instead, but as far as I can tell, it's the same). However, my bound function isn't working - does the bound function have access to the same variables as the click() function? Or maybe when using the syntax `$("#mydiv").click(function(){ $("#mydiv").hide();}`, there are hidden variables passed to the function?

Comment: If you want to pass a parameter, you can call the outside function inside of your anonymous function, and pass the parameters in that way.

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing from the other posts, you can parameterize your event handler as follows:

```
function fHardCodedFunction(someValue) {
  alert(this.id + " - " + someValue);
}


function fBindFunctionToElement() {
  var someValue = "whatever";
  $("#MyButton").bind("click", 
       function() {
         fHardCodedFunction.apply(this, [someValue]);
       }
  );
}


$(document).ready
(
  function() {
    fBindFunctionToElement();
  }
);
```

I'm using apply here because in function `fHardCodedFunction` I'd like the `this` property to refer to the `MyButton` element.  Note also that apply expects an array for the second parameter, which is why I've wrapped `someValue` in brackets.

You don't have to do it this way and can forget about this `this` property altogether if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can bind methods that written somewhere else, but you should ignore the parentheses :

```
function fHardCodedFunction(){
   //Do stuff
}

function fBindFunctionToElement(){
   $("#MyButton").bind("click", fHardCodedFunction);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this answer is tagged with **event-handling**, I suspect it would be useful to talk about the events, too.  Your immediate problem, as stated by others, is simply to use the defined function `function`, and not call `function()`.  The parens indicate to call the function,  whereas you're trying to specify the function to use.

So, how do you *handle the event?*  You only need to define it as the first argument of your function...

```
function fHardCodedFunction(event){
    console.log(event);
}

function fBindFunctionToElement(){
    $("#MyButton").bind("click", fHardCodedFunction);
}
```

The [**api.jquery.com documentation for `bind()`**](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) indicate as much, too.  I have also put together a [**very small, working demo**](https://jsbin.com/guyoqot/3/edit?html,js,output), to demonstrate *event-handling.*

*HTML...*

```
<input type="text" id="text">
<div id="main">Results appear here.</div>
```

*JavaScript...*

```
function clickFunction(e) { return $('#main').html(e.which); }
$('#text').bind('keypress', clickFunction);
```