# How to create a function which calls a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-manipulation, zooming

I'm using a jquery file which has a image zoom functionality:

http://www.albanx.com/jslibs/axzoomer.js

Everything is working fine. But now i need a feature which is not included with the plugin.
On the zoom activating event the default zoom level should be changed.

I've tryied something like this:

```
imageLoaded:function()
{
    return this.each(function()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.zoomInOut(1.5);

        // zoomInOut(1.5);
    });
},
```

But no luck... Since i'm not sure how the functions are working in jQuery, and the zoomInOut is the function inside function as i figured out...

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The function displayed before is integrated into this js file:

http://www.ifmi.lt/public/axzoomer/axzoomer-1.5.js ( Line 382 ).

For those who does not know hot the axzoomer works: you need to provide 2 images one in normal size, another the big size for zoom. Then the initial zoom starting by scaling the small image, when the scale of image is more than 1.2 then the big image is loading.

In my code since i'm using the `jquery.reel` library also i customized a bit the axzoomer approach. When zoom button is clicked then this function is being called:

```
function zoomImage ()
{
    var value = Number ( $('#image360').attr('src').split ( '_' )[1].split ( '.' )[0] );

    $('#zoom-content').load( initiateZoom );

    $('#zoom-content').attr ( 'src', 'products/1/' + value + '.jpg' );
    $('#zoom-content').attr ( 'src-big', 'product/1/zoom/' + value + '.jpg' );

    $('#zoom-content').axzoomer({
        'maxZoom':3,
        'opacity':0.5,
        'sensivity':17,
        'showControls':false,
        'zoomIn':'',
        'zoomOut':''
   });
}
```

After the small image has been loaded, the `initiateZoom` function is called.
The `axzoomer ( 'imageLoaded' );` function is reachable from js, it is called when the small image is loaded:

```
function initiateZoom() 
{
    $('#zoom-content').axzoomer ( 'enable' );
    $('#zoom-content').axzoomer ( 'imageLoaded' );
}
```

But inside of the imageLoaded ( in the axzoomer.js function starting on line 382 ) i can not reach the zoomInOut function, to zoom the image on initial load.

Comment: A function inside a function.... "We need to go deeper!" :-D

Comment: You've left out something crucial: how isn't it working? Always describe exactly what you want/expect and what you actually get, which includes any error messages. Also, the title needs to be made much more specific. It's a simple matter to write a "function which calls a function": `function foo(){}; function bar(){foo()}`.

Comment: try this one hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384037/binding-an-existing-javascript-function-in-jquery

Comment: @outis i can call the imageLoaded function, but it can not reach the zoomInOut function. And zoomInOut function is described inside the init() function as a variable.

Comment: @JevgenijDmitrijev: please update the question with the requested information. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a QA & site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: The [sample code](http://sscce.org/) doesn't look complete; it should be complete, concise and representative. Read [Writing the Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for more.

Comment: Updated. Please take a look. if you need any more information let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, made a different approach to the problem and it was solved in no time.

Here is the sollution.

the file: http://www.ifmi.lt/public/axzoomer/axzoomer-1.5+.js

1. Added new setting parameter: initialZoom ( line 32 )
2. Added the checking for the initialZoom parameter ( line 382 )

The new functionality checks for the initialZoom parameter, and if it exists, zooms the image by that amount from the center of the image when the ax-zoomer initializes.