# Event Delegation -- JQuery Skips Click

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

I am adding content [buttons & tables] to my 'container' uses the load method.

However, dynamic content requires delegation and I believe my code for this is wrong and I am somehow confusing parents/children.
When I load my page, my 'table' is loaded, without even clicking on button1.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button1").click(loadUserNameTable);
        $("#contentbox").on("click", '#table .button2', loadQuestions);

    });


function loadUserNameTable() {
        $("#contentholder").load("nametable.html");
    }
    function loadQuestions() {
        $("#contentholder").load("questions.html");
    }
    function loadPasswordChanger() {
        $("#contentholder").load("passwordchange.html");
    }
    </script>

<div id="contentholder">
<button type = "button" id="button1">Begin Password Reset</button>
</div>



 //nametable.html
<div class="table">
<table id="table1" style="margin:0 auto">
<tr>
<td>
    Enter Username: 
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="userName" value="" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
<td>

</td>
<td>
<button id="button2" style="float: left"> Submit </button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>


//questions.html

<div class="qs" id="questions" style="margin: 0 auto">
<table style="margin: 0 auto">
    <tr>
        <td>Question 1: </td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Question 2: </td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        <button id="button2" style="float: left"> Submit </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could it be perhaps because you are calling `loadUserNameTable()`? Try replacing this with `loadUserNameTable`.

Comment: Also, your markup for the `<button>` element is invalid. It is not a [void element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5) itself. It should be `<button>InnerText</button>`.

Comment: In you provided code there is neither a `#contentbox` nor a `#table` and no button with the **class** `button2` only with the **id** `button2`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included my js functions. loadUserNameTable() is the function I want to call.

Comment: @Christopher, I think you're misunderstanding JCOC611's comment. Remove the parenthesis from the function call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding an existing javascript function in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384037/binding-an-existing-javascript-function-in-jquery)

Comment: One second -- rewritting this code, sorry been a long morning and this is a mess >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is *most likely* due to the fact that you are executing your function before any event takes place. Change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").click(loadUserNameTable);
    $("#contentbox").on("click", '#table .button2', loadUserNameTable);
});
```

This is due to the fact that you were using parenthesis `()` after your function, which *executes* it immediately (and not on an event). If you put only your function name, without the parenthesis, jQuery will take care of executing it once the event takes place.

Comment: Yes, this works. It no longer instantly loads that page. However, I think I need to work on my delegation still, the button there is still giving me problems. Thank you!